# net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR in a proxy using spring

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, proxy

We have an endpoint that obtains a url from a header and then forward the request to another server located in the url it receives. It works like a proxy

```kotlin
    @PostMapping(path = ["/some_endpoint"])
    @Throws(ResponseStatusException::class)
    fun myProxy(request: RequestEntity<ByteArray>): ResponseEntity<ByteArray> {
        val headers = request.headers
        val method = request.method
        val body = request.body
        val url = request.url
        val newUrl = getUrl(headers)

        val requestCopy = RequestEntity(body, headers, method, newUrl, request.type)

        return try {
            RestTemplate().exchange(requestCopy, ByteArray::class.java)
        } catch (e: RestClientResponseException) {
            ResponseEntity<ByteArray>(e.responseBodyAsByteArray, e.responseHeaders, e.statusCode)
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly well in dev environment with http, but if we deployed it fails
In Chrome fails with:

```
net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
```

In firefox:

```
NS_ERROR_NET_INTERRUPT
```

I guess is something related to https or the nginx that we put in front of the application

I know that the call performed inside of the endpoint success with a 200, but the response we forward for some reason is not acceptable by the browser

What do you suggest? do you think I did a mistake in my code? Is there a better way to do this?

Before, we had a proxy that used the library "Spring Cloud Gateway" but we are not allowed to use that library anymore

[image: response]
[image: request]

Chrome fails:
[image: chrome fails]

Firefox fails
[image: firefox fails]